# Class member initializer:syntax and usage

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Say there is a class:

```
class person {
    int age;
    string name;

    public:
       person(int age,string name)
            :age(age),name(name)
                {}
};
```

I have the following questions:

- Can the constructor initializer(with the ":" syntax) be used somehow outside of classes?Is it just for classes?
- A variable declaration such as `int x(2)` works for obvious reasons.x is an object with value of 2.But age(age),how does that work?Is the syntax made that way to make initialization easier?
- Based on that,how come can the **parameter** age & **member** age have the same name and not confuse the compiler?Member age is in scope(as a private member),but parameter age is also in scope.When this happens with ordinary functions,the "localest" is the one that prevails.

Thanks!

Comment: That's all just the way [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't 'confuse' the compiler. Since it's a member initializer list it's scope is the same as constructor. Therefore function scope *wins* over class scope. And therefore the member `age` is initialized with the paramter `age`.

---

Normally I would not use the same name (even though certainly possible) as it's both brittle and somewhat unclear. For example:

```
struct Decision {
  bool launch_nukes;
  Decision(bool /*launch_nukes*/)  : launch_nukes(launch_nukes) {
  }
};
```

At best will only give a warning.

Comment: If that scope wins,then how does the function know about member age?How is the distinguish made?

Comment: @zach in `age(age)` the `age` outside the brackets MUST be a member. This eliminates the ambiguity. But it still smurfs with people's heads and can be used by a careless coder to add bugs later so it's generally best if you don't re-use the name.

Comment: @user4581301 Okay,that fulfills my question!

Answer (score 1):

> Can the constructor initializer(with the ":" syntax) be used somehow outside of classes?Is it just for classes?

Member initializer lists can only be used by constructors only.

> A variable declaration such as `int x(2)` works for obvious reasons.x is an object with value of `2`. But `age(age)`, how does that work? Is the syntax made that way to make initialization easier?
>
> Based on that,how come can the parameter `age` & member `age` have the same name and not confuse the compiler? Member `age` is in scope, but parameter `age` is also in scope. When this happens with ordinary functions, the "localest" is the one that prevails.

we have and expect `member(init)`, so for `member`, only members of the class are seen (and Base class or own class for delegating constructor). We can say that we are only in the scope of the class.

For `init`, indeed regular scope applies, and parameters `age`/`name` hides members with same name.